# Old question with lots of editing?

Tags: discussion, edits

Had a note about an edit to this pop up today:-

[Join 2 tables return single row for each related data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29654790/join-2-tables-return-single-row-for-each-related-data/29655058#29655058)

Someone (not the original questioner) has edited the original post (from April last year) to change the formatting, and also one of the variable names.

Then edited all the answers to match the updated variable name (plus changing the formatting).

Is this someone just being a touch over enthusiastic or is it something else (mining for badges / reputation)?

Comment: Formatting made the SQL a bit more readable, so it's ok.  Not the most important thing in the world, but it seems to help enough.  Replacing the updated variable name can be tricky so I'd advise against doing edits that touch code logic, even if it seems simple enough like a rename.

Comment: Note that the edits corrected the (bad) English which, overall, made the question much better. The same goes (IMO) for the adjusted column names – and of course then the answers had to be edited as well to prevent the inevitable "your column names are off!" comments.

Comment: To me formatting of SQL is personal preference (and some peoples preference I find just about unreadable! ). Very much disagree with changing column names

Comment: You don't agree that for these *example* tables, having clearer *example* column names makes the post more readable?

Comment: Tables names might be example ones, but wouldn't say that about column names. Especially when the only change is inserting underscores. Don't think the column name changes make it more readable or meaningful (tbh, same for the SQL and the formatting of the original posts sample data for me)

Comment: The user has over 7K so they didn't get any rep from this. I agree that adding the underscores seems unnecessary but, since the other edits do help, I wouldn't worry about it.